# 2 span tags need the text in the second span vertically centered to the first

Tags: html, css

I want to have is the text "$29" that is in big text and one colour, and after that the text, "per month" in a smaller font different colour but is aligned vertically so it appears to be in the middle of the "$29".  But nothing I tried worked.  I have:

Hoping to get the text per month centered to the "$29" text.

```css
.per {
  color: hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.whiteMoney {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="whiteMoney">$29</span>
  <span class="per">per month<span>
</p>
```

Comment: FYI: The 2nd `span` isn't closed properly, also I've made the "whiteMoney" red, otherwise people can't actually see the text

Comment: `vertical-align: center;` - you can go read up on what _valid_ values for this property would be, you don't have to _guess_ (and guess _wrong_, in this instance) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 1):

One nice, modern way to do this is with `flex` layout:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: black; /* for demo purposes */
}

.per {
  color:hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
}

.whiteMoney {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="whiteMoney">$29</span> 
<span class="per">per month<span>
</p>
```

In case I've misunderstood and you want the items side by side but their middles to align, you could try this instead:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: black; /* for demo purposes */
}

.per {
  color:hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
}

.whiteMoney {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="whiteMoney">$29</span> 
<span class="per">per month<span>
</p>
```

You could add some bottom padding to `.per` if you don't like the visual effect, say `padding-bottom: 3px`.

Answer (score 0):

set **vertical-align**:**middle**, **center** doesn't make sense for property **vertical-align**.

```css
.per{
  color:hsl(71, 73%, 54%);
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.whiteMoney{
  color: red;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight:700;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
<span class="whiteMoney">$29</span> 
<span class="per">per month<span>
</p>
```

Comment: I've made the "whiteMoney" red, otherwise people can't see the correct result